# Getting "useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component" error while testing react router component with vitest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-router, vitest

I'm new in react router and react testing and i keep getting error as in title.
I think problem lies in NavLinks in Header.

main.jsx:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Router.jsx:

```
const Router = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <App />,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <MainPage />,
        },
        {
          path: '/shop',
          element: <Shop />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};
```

app.jsx:

```
import Header from '../components/Header/Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Header.jsx:

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      <img src="https://www.kadencewp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/alogo-4.png" alt="logo" />
      <nav>
        <NavLink to="/" className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive)}>
          Main page
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/shop" className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive)}>
          Shop
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};
```

test:

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    render(<App />);

    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I tried solutions from other questions but they are using other syntax and I can't get them to work. From other posts I understand that Header is outside of router but nothing that I tried to do with it works.